# How to create required json with json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to create this JSON below using JSON.Net but i received an error of

> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray

I was able to get the output up until "cpu" but i can't create "disks" which involves array.

JSON I'm trying to make:

```
{
  "spec":{
     "name":"SampleVM",
     "cpu":{
        "hot_remove_enabled":true,
        "count":1,
        "hot_add_enabled":true,
        "cores_per_socket":1
     },
     "disks":[
        {
           "new_vmdk":{
              "capacity":1024
           }
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

My code

```cs
JObject newjson =
    new JObject(
        new JProperty("spec", 
            new JProperty("name","SampleVM"),                  
            new JProperty("cpu",new JObject
            { 
            new JProperty("hot_remove_enabled",true),
            new JProperty("count",1),
            new JProperty("hot_add_enabled",true),
            new JProperty("cores_per_socket",1)
            }),

            new JProperty("disks", new JArray(
                new JObject
                {
                    new JProperty("new_vmdk",new JObject{
                        new JProperty("capacity",1024)
                    })
                }
                ))));
```

What can i change in my code to get the exact same output as the JSON? My problem mainly lies on trying to recreate "disks" JProperty which has array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
new JObject(
    new JProperty("spec", 
        new JProperty("name","SampleVM"),
        new JProperty("cpu", // Remainder omitted.
```

What you are doing here is adding multiple `JProperty` objects **to a `JProperty`**.  A property can't have properties as children, only an object can have properties as children.

You probably want those nested properties encapsulated in an object like so:

```
var newjson =
    new JObject(
    new JProperty("spec", 
                  new JObject(
                      new JProperty("name","SampleVM"),                  
                      new JProperty("cpu",new JObject
                                    { 
                                        new JProperty("hot_remove_enabled",true),
                                        new JProperty("count",1),
                                        new JProperty("hot_add_enabled",true),
                                        new JProperty("cores_per_socket",1)
                                    }),

                      new JProperty("disks", new JArray(
                          new JObject
                          {
                              new JProperty("new_vmdk",new JObject{
                                  new JProperty("capacity",1024)
                              })
                          }
                      )))));
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AZFPM0).

Notes:

- The misleading error message *Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray* seems to come from the fact that you are trying to add **multiple** properties to a property, in which case the `JProperty` constructor assumes that since a collection is being passed in, a `JArray` should be made out of the incoming arguments -- and fails, since the arguments are all of type `JProperty`.

  If I add just one property to a property like so:

  ```
  new JObject(
      new JProperty("spec", 
                    new JProperty("name","SampleVM")
                   )
  );
  ```

  I get a less misleading message *Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.*  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/puaLTe).